# How can I create a barplot with two variables side by side?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the following df:

[image]

I would like to have a graphic to show how many Victims and how many Deaths are each hour. So I can compare them both each hour.

I am not sure if I need to put the variable hour into a qualitative variable, like this:

[image]

I tried in different ways but I always have a problem.

I am expecting something like this:

[image]

Where I can get the total of victims and the total of deaths like "Hombres" and "Mujeres" in the last graph, and the different columns as the different hours, and if not as "Diurno" and "Nocturno".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You are looking for a grouped bar plot, see https://www.data-to-viz.com/graph/barplot.html for example

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this (example with the first data set):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-total_h.HORA) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(total_h.HORA), y=value, fill= name))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
  labs(fill = "", x="")+
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("Mujeres", "Victimas"), 
                    values = c("orange", "darkolivegreen4")) +
  theme_bw()+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = NULL)+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

data:

```
df <- structure(list(total_h.HORA = 0:9, total_h.TOTAL_MU30DF = c(49L, 
20L, 35L, 27L, 23L, 25L, 51L, 62L, 61L, 68L), total_h.TOTAL_VICTIMAS_30DF = c(1943L, 
1301L, 920L, 780L, 771L, 1052L, 1887L, 3920L, 5228L, 5492L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```